# Why is SuperFish overriding all my list styles?

Tags: jquery, html, css, superfish

I'm currently using SuperFish - http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#download - for the first time in a project of mine.

My global navigation works as intended, however, regular page lists are displaying the same styling as my Superfish navigation. I have looked through my CSS, everything is written pseudo-like and should not be affecting anything. Here is the css file:

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {`
 margin:   0;
 padding:  0;
 list-style:  none;
}
.sf-menu {
 line-height: 1.0;
 width: 960px;
 background: #000;
}
.sf-menu ul {
 position:  absolute;
 top:   -999em;
 width:   8em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
 width:   100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
 visibility:  inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
 float:   left;
 position:  relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
 display:  block;
 position:  relative;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
 left:   0;
 top:   2.5em; /* match top ul list item height */
 z-index:  99;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   8em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
 top:   -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
 left:   10em; /* match ul width */
 top:   0;
}

/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
 float:   left;
}
.sf-menu a {
 padding:   .75em 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
 color:   #13a;
}
.sf-menu li {
 background:  #000;
}
.sf-menu li li {
 background:  #000;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
 background:  #000;
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
 background:  #000;
 outline:  0;
}`
```

Sorry for the above mess, I am having trouble with the backtick escapes for this code. If you are able to look at it in an editor or some sort..you can see that all styles should be applied to any lists with the .sf-menu class applied.

This is not the case. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this sounds stupid but you're sure you have closed the div with the sf-menu class?

Comment: Wow...such a simple mistake. Thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue with superfish menu. My problem was because of the Custom CSS from the Superfish Module Menu (in Joomla Admin menu). I had there:

```
li {
        float: left;
    display:inline;
        font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
li a {
        color: #000;
}
```

After removing the

```
float: left;
display: inline;
```

It worked.

I think the Custom CSS from superfish is overriding the css from template.css.

Comment: If those are the exact styles you're using, then yes, it would do that, because the selector selects **all** list item elements. You should probably do what the OP did there, which is to limit the selectors down with a class or id selector, to select only the menus and nothing else